# Why is SD card failing to begin?

Tags: sd-card

I recently bought a micro SD storage shield for my arduino project, this is the [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SL0QWDU). My final goal is to log information every 100 ms about the temperature and pressure of my device using another one of my sensors. However, I started by testing out the SD card through the SdInfo class that comes as an example with the SdFat library. This is the outcome (through the Serial monitor):

```
SdFat version: 20160719

Assuming the SD is the only SPI device.
Edit DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT to disable another device.

Assuming the SD chip select pin is: 10
Edit SD_CHIP_SELECT to change the SD chip select pin.

type any character to start

init time: 748 ms

Card type: SDHC

Manufacturer ID: 0X28
OEM ID: BE
Product: 68BHO
Version: 0.8
Serial number: 0XD50B3A66
Manufacturing date: 11/2010

cardSize: 32026.66 MB (MB = 1,000,000 bytes)
flashEraseSize: 128 blocks
eraseSingleBlock: true
OCR: 0XC0FF8000

SD Partition Table
part,boot,type,start,length
1,0X0,0XC,8192,62543872
2,0X0,0X0,0,0
3,0X0,0X0,0,0
4,0X0,0X0,0,0

Volume is FAT32
blocksPerCluster: 64
clusterCount: 976992
freeClusters: 976905
freeSpace: 32011.22 MB (MB = 1,000,000 bytes)
fatStartBlock: 9310
fatCount: 2
blocksPerFat: 7633
rootDirStart: 2
dataStartBlock: 24576

type any character to start

cardBegin failed
SD errorCode: 0XA
SD errorData: 0X5
```

This is the code of the class SdInfo:

```
/*
 * This program attempts to initialize an SD card and analyze its structure.
 */
#include <SPI.h>
#include "SdFat.h"
/*
 * SD chip select pin.  Common values are:
 *
 * Arduino Ethernet shield, pin 4.
 * SparkFun SD shield, pin 8.
 * Adafruit SD shields and modules, pin 10.
 * Default SD chip select is the SPI SS pin.
 */
const uint8_t SD_CHIP_SELECT = SS;
/*
 * Set DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT to disable a second SPI device.
 * For example, with the Ethernet shield, set DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT
 * to 10 to disable the Ethernet controller.
 */
const int8_t DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT = -1;
SdFat sd;

// serial output steam
ArduinoOutStream cout(Serial);

// global for card size
uint32_t cardSize;

// global for card erase size
uint32_t eraseSize;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// store error strings in flash
#define sdErrorMsg(msg) sdErrorMsg_F(F(msg));
void sdErrorMsg_F(const __FlashStringHelper* str) {
  cout << str << endl;
  if (sd.card()->errorCode()) {
    cout << F("SD errorCode: ");
    cout << hex << int(sd.card()->errorCode()) << endl;
    cout << F("SD errorData: ");
    cout << int(sd.card()->errorData()) << dec << endl;
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint8_t cidDmp() {
  cid_t cid;
  if (!sd.card()->readCID(&cid)) {
    sdErrorMsg("readCID failed");
    return false;
  }
  cout << F("\nManufacturer ID: ");
  cout << hex << int(cid.mid) << dec << endl;
  cout << F("OEM ID: ") << cid.oid[0] << cid.oid[1] << endl;
  cout << F("Product: ");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << cid.pnm[i];
  }
  cout << F("\nVersion: ");
  cout << int(cid.prv_n) << '.' << int(cid.prv_m) << endl;
  cout << F("Serial number: ") << hex << cid.psn << dec << endl;
  cout << F("Manufacturing date: ");
  cout << int(cid.mdt_month) << '/';
  cout << (2000 + cid.mdt_year_low + 10 * cid.mdt_year_high) << endl;
  cout << endl;
  return true;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint8_t csdDmp() {
  csd_t csd;
  uint8_t eraseSingleBlock;
  if (!sd.card()->readCSD(&csd)) {
    sdErrorMsg("readCSD failed");
    return false;
  }
  if (csd.v1.csd_ver == 0) {
    eraseSingleBlock = csd.v1.erase_blk_en;
    eraseSize = (csd.v1.sector_size_high << 1) | csd.v1.sector_size_low;
  } else if (csd.v2.csd_ver == 1) {
    eraseSingleBlock = csd.v2.erase_blk_en;
    eraseSize = (csd.v2.sector_size_high << 1) | csd.v2.sector_size_low;
  } else {
    cout << F("csd version error\n");
    return false;
  }
  eraseSize++;
  cout << F("cardSize: ") << 0.000512*cardSize;
  cout << F(" MB (MB = 1,000,000 bytes)\n");

  cout << F("flashEraseSize: ") << int(eraseSize) << F(" blocks\n");
  cout << F("eraseSingleBlock: ");
  if (eraseSingleBlock) {
    cout << F("true\n");
  } else {
    cout << F("false\n");
  }
  return true;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// print partition table
uint8_t partDmp() {
  cache_t *p = sd.vol()->cacheClear();
  if (!p) {
    sdErrorMsg("cacheClear failed");
    return false;
  }
  if (!sd.card()->readBlock(0, p->data)) {
    sdErrorMsg("read MBR failed");
    return false;
  }
  for (uint8_t ip = 1; ip < 5; ip++) {
    part_t *pt = &p->mbr.part[ip - 1];
    if ((pt->boot & 0X7F) != 0 || pt->firstSector > cardSize) {
      cout << F("\nNo MBR. Assuming Super Floppy format.\n");
      return true;
    }
  }
  cout << F("\nSD Partition Table\n");
  cout << F("part,boot,type,start,length\n");
  for (uint8_t ip = 1; ip < 5; ip++) {
    part_t *pt = &p->mbr.part[ip - 1];
    cout << int(ip) << ',' << hex << int(pt->boot) << ',' << int(pt->type);
    cout << dec << ',' << pt->firstSector <<',' << pt->totalSectors << endl;
  }
  return true;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void volDmp() {
  cout << F("\nVolume is FAT") << int(sd.vol()->fatType()) << endl;
  cout << F("blocksPerCluster: ") << int(sd.vol()->blocksPerCluster()) << endl;
  cout << F("clusterCount: ") << sd.vol()->clusterCount() << endl;
  cout << F("freeClusters: ");
  uint32_t volFree = sd.vol()->freeClusterCount();
  cout <<  volFree << endl;
  float fs = 0.000512*volFree*sd.vol()->blocksPerCluster();
  cout << F("freeSpace: ") << fs << F(" MB (MB = 1,000,000 bytes)\n");
  cout << F("fatStartBlock: ") << sd.vol()->fatStartBlock() << endl;
  cout << F("fatCount: ") << int(sd.vol()->fatCount()) << endl;
  cout << F("blocksPerFat: ") << sd.vol()->blocksPerFat() << endl;
  cout << F("rootDirStart: ") << sd.vol()->rootDirStart() << endl;
  cout << F("dataStartBlock: ") << sd.vol()->dataStartBlock() << endl;
  if (sd.vol()->dataStartBlock() % eraseSize) {
    cout << F("Data area is not aligned on flash erase boundaries!\n");
    cout << F("Download and use formatter from www.sdcard.org!\n");
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Wait for USB Serial 
  while (!Serial) {
    SysCall::yield();
  }

  // use uppercase in hex and use 0X base prefix
  cout << uppercase << showbase << endl;

  // F stores strings in flash to save RAM
  cout << F("SdFat version: ") << SD_FAT_VERSION << endl;
  if (DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT < 0) {
    cout << F(
           "\nAssuming the SD is the only SPI device.\n"
           "Edit DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT to disable another device.\n");
  } else {
    cout << F("\nDisabling SPI device on pin ");
    cout << int(DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT) << endl;
    pinMode(DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(DISABLE_CHIP_SELECT, HIGH);
  }
  cout << F("\nAssuming the SD chip select pin is: ") <<int(SD_CHIP_SELECT);
  cout << F("\nEdit SD_CHIP_SELECT to change the SD chip select pin.\n");
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void loop() {
  // Read any existing Serial data.
  do {
    delay(10);
  } while (Serial.available() && Serial.read() >= 0);

  // F stores strings in flash to save RAM
  cout << F("\ntype any character to start\n");
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    SysCall::yield();
  }

  uint32_t t = millis();
  // initialize the SD card at SPI_HALF_SPEED to avoid bus errors with
  // breadboards.  use SPI_FULL_SPEED for better performance.
  if (!sd.cardBegin(SD_CHIP_SELECT, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) {
    sdErrorMsg("\ncardBegin failed");
    return;
  }
  t = millis() - t;

  cardSize = sd.card()->cardSize();
  if (cardSize == 0) {
    sdErrorMsg("cardSize failed");
    return;
  }
  cout << F("\ninit time: ") << t << " ms" << endl;
  cout << F("\nCard type: ");
  switch (sd.card()->type()) {
  case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1:
    cout << F("SD1\n");
    break;

  case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2:
    cout << F("SD2\n");
    break;

  case SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC:
    if (cardSize < 70000000) {
      cout << F("SDHC\n");
    } else {
      cout << F("SDXC\n");
    }
    break;

  default:
    cout << F("Unknown\n");
  }
  if (!cidDmp()) {
    return;
  }
  if (!csdDmp()) {
    return;
  }
  uint32_t ocr;
  if (!sd.card()->readOCR(&ocr)) {
    sdErrorMsg("\nreadOCR failed");
    return;
  }
  cout << F("OCR: ") << hex << ocr << dec << endl;
  if (!partDmp()) {
    return;
  }
  if (!sd.fsBegin()) {
    sdErrorMsg("\nFile System initialization failed.\n");
    return;
  }
  volDmp();
}
```

I have noticed that the SD card is detected only upon start up, after that it all goes to errors. I had the same situation using the default SdInfo class from the built-in Arduino examples, sometimes it would register the card, sometimes it wouldn't. **Why does this happen and how can I ensure it always reads the card?**

I have already read [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17062/sd-card-fails-to-initialize) question and ensured my wiring is proper and I have also formatted my card using the software and SdCard.org, it is a Fat32 format.

This is my setup:

[image: Image 1]

and

[image: Image 2]

Comment: That's not the code that prints those messages.

Comment: @slash-dev my mistake, updated the post

Comment: A guess, so this is only a comment, not an answer:  When formatting an SDCard, recent versions of Windows stopped putting partition information onto SDCards.  You can override this weird behavior if you want.  Missing partition information might cause some SDCard drivers to fail.  Just something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

SdInfo is an example, but I hope you know there's no reason to call `sd.begin`  to re-initialize the SD library.  The example is really intended to scan several different cards, not the same card.

`sd.begin` is normally something you would do once, in `setup`, even if something else is using SPI (e.g., Ethernet).  You probably won't get this error in your "real" sketch.

**But to answer your question:**

I see that your card takes a long time to initialize (almost a full second).  The error code says that the card does not re-initialize within 2 seconds.  I had a [similar problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21368#21373), and the solution was to edit the SD library and slow down how quickly it asked the card, "Are you initialized yet?"

Error code 0x0A is SD_CARD_ERROR_ACMD41, so perhaps you can use the same technique in this loop, line 171 of SdSpiCard.cpp:

```
  // initialize card and send host supports SDHC if SD2
  arg = type() == SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2 ? 0X40000000 : 0;

  while (cardAcmd(ACMD41, arg) != R1_READY_STATE) {
    // check for timeout
    if (((uint16_t)millis() - t0) > SD_INIT_TIMEOUT) {
      error(SD_CARD_ERROR_ACMD41);
      goto fail;
    }
    delay( 150 ); // <-- wait a little
  }
```

#### Update

There is a related question and answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/sd-begin-fails-second-time).  Calling `sd.begin` twice is actually an open issue in the library.

Comment: I only initialize the card once at "sd.cardBegin(SD_CHIP_SELECT, SPI_HALF_SPEED)", and in your code, what does cardAcmd() method mean?

Comment: `loop` gets called over and over. It pauses to wait for a character, then continues.  When it gets to the end of the test, it returns.  Then `loop` gets called again. That's why its called "loop".

Comment: Ah okay, so everytime I run the loop (aka. every time I type a character), it is trying to initialize a card that has already been initialized. I don't really want to copy paste your code, since I don't understand what the cardAcmd() method does and why you have arg variable. However, wouldn't a good alternative be just initializing the card during setup?

Comment: Hmm... I might have suggested that in the first two paragraphs. :D  No need to modify the SdFat library! Be sure to press that green triangle (Accept) if that works for you.